# SimpleCursorTreeAdapter with two levels

Tags: android, simplecursortreeadapter

For my project I have this scenario where I want to put one SimpleCursorTreeAdapter into another one to make it two level tree. Children of the first SimpleCursorTreeAdpater have their own children too. How can I achieve this? I searched but couldn't find any example of this scenario, but I am sure I am not the first one who has encountered this type of case.

Comment: if you using expandable list view, your children view can be a expandable list view to show the children

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that I came across sometime back while I was faced with a similar question - https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

When dealing with such layouts, keep in mind that the calls to findViewById() are quite expensive and you will need to utilize the ViewHolder pattern and threading to be efficient and have good performance.